# Is it possible to force Phonegap videoplayer plugin to open in landscape?

Tags: android, video, plugins, cordova

I have an application that needs to be either forced to landscape or portrait and I would want extend this to the intents I use to open other applications.

So my intent is the excellent [plugin](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.de/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html) for PhoneGap by Simon MacDonald. And as the video that I want to be played is shot in landscape it would be nice to have the video player to also be in landscape. (Yes, specific videos, not random). As the html5 video tag is broken I'm stuck.

Screen orientation changes to my knowledge are done either in android manifest, using a [plugin](https://github.com/champierre/pg-plugin-screen-orientation) for Phonegap(cant get hold of the opening application) or programmatically with setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); I have tried all these versions but as I'm crap at Java I probably have tinkered in wrong parts and bits. Thus I have no code to troubleshoot, because anything I have done hasn't had any effect or resulted in any error messages.

So dear internet, shed your wisdom upon me.